# Substitute variable in sed inside Makefile

Tags: bash, sed, makefile

I've been throught all possible answers in SO but still I cannot make my script work.

I have a query script in SPARQL with a line that needs to substitute the mark **%contributor%** by a variable between "<>"

```
?link dcterms:contributor %contributor%
```

Into

```
 ?link dcterms:contributor <http://newurl>
```

If I execute the code in the shell, the substitution is done properly and I see my query with the **%contributor%** tag successfully substituted. But when executed inside a Makefile, even with the double **$$** dollar to allow the expansion of variables I don't manage to get it done.

```
for l in `cat sref.csv`; do \
    QUERY=$$(cat queries/table_knowledge.rq | sed "s@%contributor%@<$$l>@g") ; \
    echo $$QUERY ; \
done
```

Also like this it does not work:

```
QUERY=$$(cat queries/table_knowledge.rq | sed 's/%contributor%/<$(l)>/g') ; \
```

or

```
QUERY=$$(cat queries/table_knowledge.rq | sed 's/%contributor%/<${l}>/g') ; \
```

Comment: First, "I don't manage to get it done" is not a useful problem report.  What exactly happens?  What does make print?  Do you see a bunch of blank lines?  No output?  Please cut/paste results.  Your first version looks right to me (the second or third versions cannot work because you use `''` quoting and you're using make variable references but you're trying to access shell variables).  If you're still stuck I recommend adding `set -x;` before the `for l ...` so that the shell prints the commands it's trying to invoke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes so that sed would expand variables. 
Use a separator different than `/` since the replacement contains `/`

`QUERY=$(cat queries/table_knowledge.rq | sed "s|%contributor%|<${l}>|g") ;`

***Test:***

```
$ test="http://test.com"
$ echo "?link dcterms:contributor %contributor%" > source.file
$ x=$(cat source.file|sed "s|%contributor%|<${test}>|g")
$ echo $x
?link dcterms:contributor <http://test.com>
```

Comment: The first version in the question does use double-quotes.  Also the first version uses `@` as a separator not `/`.  The question states that it works from the shell, which you are just re-asserting here.  The problem is that it doesn't work from within a makefile recipe.